# Getting values from a PHP Object

Tags: php, json, object

I am trying to figure out how to echo the **genre** value from an object created with this programme [wrapper](https://github.com/php-tmdb/api) that requests json data from ['The Movie Database'](https://www.themoviedb.org/). I'm so stuck and grappling to understand Object-oriented PHP so any help would be great.
I think the fact it is 'nested' (if that's the correct terminology) might be the issue.

```
<?php 

    include("tmdb/tmdb-api.php");

    $apikey = "myapi_key";
    $tmdb = new TMDB($apikey, 'en', true);
    $idMovie = 206647;

    $movie = $tmdb->getMovie($idMovie);

    // returns a Movie Object
    echo $movie->getTitle().'<br>';
    echo $movie->getVoteAverage().'<br>';
    echo '<img src="'. $tmdb->getImageURL('w185') . $movie->getPoster() .'"/></li><br>';
    echo $movie->genres->id[28]->name;
?>
```

All of the other values are echoed just fine but I can't seem to get at genres. The json data looks like this ( some of it).

```
    { 
    "adult":false, 
    "backdrop_path":"\/fa9qPNpmLtk7yC5KZj9kIxlDJvG.jpg",
    "belongs_to_collection":{
        "id":645,
        "name":"James Bond Collection",
        "poster_path":"\/HORpg5CSkmeQlAolx3bKMrKgfi.jpg",
        "backdrop_path":"\/6VcVl48kNKvdXOZfJPdarlUGOsk.jpg" },
        "budget": 0,
        "genres":[
            { "id": 28, "name": "Action" }, 
            { "id": 12, "name": "Adventure" }, 
            { "id": 80, "name": "Crime" } 
        ], 
    "homepage":"http:\/\/www.sonypictures.com\/movies\/spectre\/",
    "id":206647,
    "imdb_id":"tt2379713",
    "original_language":"en",
    "original_title":"SPECTRE",
    "overview":"A cryptic message from Bond\u2019s past sends him on a trail to uncover a sinister organization. While M battles political forces to keep the secret service alive, Bond peels back the layers of deceit to reveal the terrible truth behind SPECTRE."
}
```

Comment: $movie->genres is an array of genres, so just access them by key like you would a normal array. $movie->genres[0]->name ... You might want to loop over them though, like foreach ($movie->genres as $genre) { echo $genre->name }

Comment: If you're having trouble reading the json I'd suggest pretty printing it.. echo '<pre>'; print_r($json);

Comment: It's a json object. Decode your data.

Answer (score 2):

```
$movie->genres->id[28]->name
```

This assumes that id is an array and you want the item with index number 28 from it. What you want is the item *containing* an id with the value 28 without knowing its index number.

There's no easy way to get to it. You'd have to loop over the array `$movie->genres` and output the right one. 
Maybe like this:

```
$n = 28;
// loop over genres-array
foreach($movie->genres as $i=>$g){
    // check if id of item has right value and if so print it
    if($g->id == $n){
        echo $g->name;
        // skip rest of loop if you only want one 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got this working and returning an expected value.             public function getCasts() {
return $this->_data['casts']['cast'][0]['name'];
} How can I loop through this array to give all the names in this array?

Comment: Try something like this: `foreach($this->_data['casts']['cast'] as $i=>$c){echo $c['name'];}`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php (in case you need clarification about the foreach loop..)